# Running Terraform from PowerShell in an Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run [Terraform](https://terraform.io) from a PowerShell step in a YAML-configured Azure DevOps Pipeline, but I can't get it to accept my incantation: instead of initializing the state, it prints the usage instructions and exits.

I've tried a number of combinations of with/without quotes for the `-backend-config` parameter, but nothing seems to work.

If I cut-and-paste the script into a `ps1` file locally and run it, everything works as expected.

What is wrong with my incantation of `./terraform.exe init` here?

Here's the pipeline configuration, in its entirety:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'win1803'

steps:
- powershell: |
    # Download the Terraform executable into the current directory
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    $url = 'https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.8/terraform_0.11.8_windows_amd64.zip'
    $output = "$PSScriptRoot\terraform.zip"

    Write-Host "Downloading from $url to $output"
    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)

    Expand-Archive $output -DestinationPath . -Force

    Get-ChildItem
  displayName: 'Download Terraform executable'
- powershell: |
    # Create a config file with secrets, and initialize Terraform
    "storage_account_name = `"$env:TerraformStateAccountName`"" | Out-File "./terraform-state.secrets.tfvars" -Append
    "access_key = `"$env:TerraformStateAccountKey`"" | Out-File "./terraform-state.secrets.tfvars" -Append
    "container_name = `"$env:TerraformStateContainer`"" | Out-File "./terraform-state.secrets.tfvars" -Append

    ./terraform.exe init -backend-config=./terraform-state.secrets.tfvars -input=false
  env:
    TerraformStateAccountName: $(Terraform.State.StorageAccountName)
    TerraformStateAccountKey: $(Terraform.State.StorageAccountKey)
    TerraformStateContainer: $(Terraform.State.ContainerName)
  displayName: 'Initialize Terraform'
```

Comment: what gets printed exactly?

Comment: @4c74356b41: The same thing as when I run `./terraform.exe init -foo` locally, except locally I get a final line saying `flag provided but not defined: -foo` while on the build server I get no message at all.

Comment: @4c74356b41: As I wrote, it is not _exactly_ the same. It is the same _with one exception_: the last line of the local output of `./terraform.exe init -foo` is not included on the build server. (If you want to be rude, at least don't put words in my mouth in order to have something to be rude about.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the blanks surrounding the `=` sign.

I prefer using environment variables, documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/azurerm.html):

1. `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`
2. `ARM_CLIENT_ID`
3. `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET`
4. `ARM_TENANT_ID`
5. `ARM_OBJECT_ID`
6. `ARM_ACCESS_KEY`

You can also initialize Terraform variables using environment variables as documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/environment-variables.html).

Comment: Removing the blanks surrounding the `=` made no difference. Will try the env var approach (but I find it a little annoying that I can't specify the storage account name and container name with env vars...)

Comment: Specifying the Access Key as an environment variable, and the others as inlined config vars (`-backend-config="storage_account_name=$env:ARM_ACCOUNT_NAME"` etc) seems to work well. Still a little annoying, but since it works and I'm not going to have to look at this part of the code again, I don't care :)